# Destroy Angular Service when route change

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-providers

I have a complexe module called `MyPageModule` importing several modules which provides Service with following annotation `@Injectable( { providedIn: 'root' } )`.

This module is imported by lazy loading like this:

```
// AppRoutingModule
...
 {
    path: 'my-page',
    loadChildren: './lazy-loader-modules/lazy-loader-mypage/lazy-loader-mypage.module#LazyLoaderMyPageModule'
 }

...
```

```
// LazyLoaderMyPageModule
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyPageModule
  ]
})
export class LazyLoaderMyPageModule { }
```

**Behavior that I want (not the case actually):**
When url is different of /my-page/*, I'd like that all services imported by MyPageModule are destroyed.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a root component on your lazy loaded module with a router-outlet and add providers on component metadata

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-page-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  styleUrls: ['./my-page-root.component.scss'],
  providers:[MyPageService, MyPageOtherService]
}) 
class MyPageRootComponent {}
```

Change your lazy loaded module routes to be:

```
const routes= [
 { 
    path: '',
    component: MyPageRootComponent
    children: [
      // all of your routes
    ]
 }
]
```

When MyPageRootComponent is destroyed all of your services will be destroyed.

**Edit:**

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-load-destory-services

Comment: When I do this, I have the error: `No provider for ... ` even when service is in component providers

Comment: You need to remove the providedIn: 'root' property from the services. I've added a stackblitz with an example to the answer.

Comment: My prob comes with MatDialog which are in entryComponent, so out of scope. So I need to pass service in Data to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  providedIn: UserModule,
```

[Read more](https://angular.io/guide/providers#provider-scope)

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide your services into the module.

Remove the

```
{ providedIn: 'root' }
```

And use this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyPageModule
  ],
  providers: [MyServiceOne, MyServiceTwo]
})
```

Everytime the module gets destroyed, the services follow.

Comment: Already do this, the service is always active. For exemple, my service store a GUID set byMyPageComponent at init. I go to "/example" then return to "/my-page", the older GUID is always present.

Comment: Where is there documentation about when or even if Angular modules are destroyed?